# Truffle command not found after installation

Tags: npm, blockchain, ethereum, truffle

I installed truffle through `npm` with the following:

> sudo npm install -g truffle

but when I run truffle list on the console it just gives me

> bash: truffle: command not found

Comment: What OS is that, Ubuntu 16.4?

Answer (score 33):

I had a similar problem. I ran `npm i -g truffle` and then when I tried to run `truffle init` I got an error: `zsh: command not found: truffle`.  What solved it for me is to create a local node_modules with truffle installed in it, and then run that copy.

1. run `npm init` and make a new npm project
2. run `npm i truffle`
3. run `./node_modules/.bin/truffle init` and it should work!

Comment: thank you for reminding me to keep my dependencies local and initing my project properly...this fixed everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's works for me after an afternoon of research and test !!

Answer (score 22):

Please make sure you have the latest version of npm and node installed. I had the same issue, I updated npm and node to latest version and it worked.

`npm install -g truffle` works.

Answer (score 9):

After installing truffle:

> npm install -g truffle

Run on your project folder:

> npx truffle init

Comment: I installed truffle in my local project - 'npm install truffle' ...then when I tried to run 'truffle init', I got the error 'zsh: command not found: truffle'....
I upgraded to a more recent version of Node & same error....
Running 'npx truffle init' worked like a charm!!!

Comment: did not work for me

Answer (score 6):

I did it on a Virtual box and had the same issue, but it worked after I restarted the computer.  Hopefully that works for you too

Comment: Thanks! Strange that this works. I'm also on VirtualBox Linux VM.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following to your `path` system variable.

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

(This folder contains the `truffle.cmd` file)

I have tried and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything. Followed the instruction on official truffle website and above answers.
Still it didn't seem to worked.

Finally, this worked for me.
Go to `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

There you will find `truffle.cmd` Double click on it and your done.

Answer (score 2):

`npm i truffle` does the exact same thing as `npm install -g truffle` except that installs it globally, and without `-g` it will be installed on the local folder. Try to update the npm, node, and probably you have a broken node installation from previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `npm install -g truffle` worked for me instead of `npm i truffle`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me, but I did:

1. nix truffle unbox react
2. truffle develop
3. atom . //opens up the react file project in the atom platform

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with your command like

```
npx truffle <your command>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should add `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm` (it contains truffle.cmd file) to the path user variables. I have tried and it works

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom path for your packages, then make sure that you are exporting it when the terminal loads.

For bash:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

For zsh:

```
nano ~./zshrc
```

And add your custom path, most of the time this will be "npm-global".

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

#### These are two simple steps the properly solve this problem for Linux Users:

1- Configure `npm` to install software globally in your home directory as follows :

```sh
mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

```sh
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

2- If you are using `bash`, then execute the following:

```sh
echo -n "export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
```

However, if you are using `zsh` instead, then execute the following command:

```sh
echo -n "export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Note that, if you are using both `bash` and `zsh`, it is better to execute the two commands above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing the following commands:-

1. `npm uninstall -g truffle`
2. `sudo npm install -g truffle` Be aware when using sudo(root)

Then it works when I use the below command

`truffle init` in my dir. Basically it will bootstrap