# Unable to install Truffle - Command Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, npm, truffle

I am unable to install Truffle on my Windows 10. I am running latest versions of npm and node. I have tried uninstalling and then reinstalling but it still doesn't work.

I have installed Truffle using the command

```
npm install -g truffle
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: error image]

Comment: PS - I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148521/truffle-not-working-after-installing-it but doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37296/i-cant-run-truffle-commands-in-powershell-ise

Comment: rename `truffle.js`  to `truffle-config.js`

Comment: Where is `truffle.js` @MaheshKaria?